# How do you view a log created during gitlab-runner exec?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am testing a GitLab CI pipeline with `gitlab-runner exec`. During a script, Boost ran into an error, and it created a log file. I want to view this log file, but I do not know how to.

`.gitlab-ci.yml` in project directory:

```
image: alpine

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

build:
  script:
  - apk add cmake
  - cd include/boost
  - sh bootstrap.sh
```

I test this on my machine with:

```
sudo gitlab-runner exec docker build --timeout 3600
```

The last several lines of the output:

```
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset ... 
Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
FATAL: exit code 1
```

`bootstrap.log` is what I would like to view.

Appending `- cat bootstrap.log` to `.gitlab-ci.yml` does not output the file contents because the runner exits before this line. I tried looking though past containers with `sudo docker ps -a`, but this does not show the one that GitLab Runner used. How can I open `bootstrap.log`?

Comment: For the time being, I just tested the commands on a Docker container I created outside of GitLab Runner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare an artifact for the log:

```
image: alpine

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

build:
  script:
    - apk add cmake
    - cd include/boost
    - sh bootstrap.sh

  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - include/boost/bootstrap.log
```

Afterwards, you will be able to download the log file via the web interface.

Note that using `when: on_failure` will ensure that `bootstrap.log` will only be collected if the build fails, saving disk space on successful builds.